# How to ignore a specific breaking change in a protobuf file?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I need to remove a field from a protobuf message.

This field is unused across our entire organisation.

We have FILE_NO_DELETE enabled which prevents us to accidentally remove fields.

How to tell the `buf check breaking` command included in our CI to ignore a specific breaking change ?

In other words, what would be the protobuf equivalent of `// eslint-disable-next-line ...` ?

Comment: just a secondary option (I'm not familiar with the tool/check you're using) - you could mark the field `[deprecated=true]` for now?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Marc. Actually that's what I did for now :-)